# Can't open file downloaded via response()->download()

Tags: php, laravel

I have a method which is responsible for downloading a file.

```
$attachment = KnowledgeDatabaseAttachments::where('id', $id)->first();
if ($attachment) {
    $filesPath = storage_path('app/knowledge_database_attachments');
    return response()->download($filesPath . '/' . $attachment->physical_name);
}
```

After download, when I try to open it (this is an error message from my OS):

```
Could not load image '88ebb9c0-11af-11e8-b056-b1568dc848cb.jpg'.
Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x0a 0xff)
```

File is saved like so:

```
$filesPath = storage_path('app/knowledge_database_attachments');
$physicalName = Uuid::generate() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$file->move($filesPath, $physicalName);

KnowledgeDatabaseAttachments::create([
    'knowledge_database_id' => $page->id,
    'name' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),
    'physical_name' => $physicalName
]);
```

File exist in that directory, and the downloaded file has correct size and name.

**Funny part** is that I can also create a newsletter which will include this file. When I create newsletter file is copied:

```
$extension = explode('.', $attachment->physical_name)[1];
$newPhysicalName = Uuid::generate() . '.' . $extension;
File::copy($attachment->getPathAttribute(), $storagePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $newPhysicalName);

SendMailAttachments::create([
    'mail_id' => $mail->id,
    'filename' => $attachment->name,
    'physical_name' => $newPhysicalName,
]);
```

And then, in the newsletter edit view I can as well download this file, with this (identical as above) method:

```
$attachment = SendMailAttachments::where('mail_id', $mailId)->where('filename', $attachmentName)->first();
if ($attachment) {
    $filesPath = storage_path('app/sendmail_attachments');
    return response()->download($filesPath . '/' . $attachment->physical_name);
}
```

**And it works - file is correctly downloaded and I can open it.**

Why I cant open file downloaded with first method?

I use Laravel 5.1 and Ubuntu 16.04 (if that matters).

**EDIT**

When I run `file` command on a downloaded file the result is `data`. When I run it on file in storage, the result is correct `JPEG image data`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add headers with response
[View docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#file-downloads)

```
$headers = array('Content-Type' => ' image/jpeg');
$filesPath = storage_path('app/knowledge_database_attachments');
return response()->download($filesPath,$attachment->physical_name,$headers);
```

Note: Symfony HttpFoundation, which manages file downloads, requires the file being downloaded to have an ASCII file name.

Comment: 88ebb9c0-11af-11e8-b056-b1568dc848cb.jpg is a correct ASCII file name and I already tried with headers, didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I have something being output before the image stream.

Temporary solution:

```
$response = response()->download($filesPath . '/' . $attachment->physical_name);
ob_end_clean();
return $response;
```

Permanent solution:
Find whats being output and remove it.

Found this here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/image-is-being-thrown-as-a-white-blank-image?page=1